# How to troubleshoot spring mvc mapping issue?

Tags: spring, mapping, pojo

I have a simple Spring program, the backend is Spring MVC with Restful web service, the front end is pure HTML + ajax.

My problem is, when I try to use the following to map a HTTP request params to a pojo, it always fails:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/books", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public @ResponseBody
    String updateBook(BookInfo book)
```

Here I use PUT method, because it's a modification operation. There's no exception, but I get nothing injected into book object.

With same HTTP request parameters, if I change the method to POST, and client send it via a POST, it would be success:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/books", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> addBook(BookInfo book)
```

This time book will always get the filled.

Why there's difference between PUT and POST? or it's the issue of return type? (one is ResponseBody, the other is ResponseEntity)? Or, if you use PUT, then the pojo must be in persistent context?

How should I investigate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think its not the problem with your configuration or code.
In Spring Framework there is a filter provided named **HiddenHttpMethodFilter** that serves all the method but initially it will do the POST request but with a hidden **_method** form field. And this filter reads this hidden field value and then changes the method value accordingly. Please refere [this link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) to know more about this. I think configuring with this filter will resolve your problem.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Hi japs, thanks for the tips. I'll give it a try and feed back.

Comment: You are welcome. I am pretty sure that this will resolve your problem. But I recommend you to once go through the link I have provided. :-)

Comment: It's turned out to be a real mapping issue, that at client, I should use dojo.xhrPut({url:'path/to/resource',putData:data,headers:{..."application/json"}, and at the server side, I should add @requestBody before the mapped bean, to ensure spring to map from request body, other than url. After made this change, PUT method can work. However, I'm still investigating what's the difference between dojo.xhrPut({putData:data}) and dojo.xhrPut({content:data}), sounds like this is the matter

Comment: I'm not aware about dojo. I've never used it. But I'm pretty sure that the problem in your question is solved. :-)